# On the Fourier transform of $f(x)=e^{-x^2+2x}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

So, I have the $f(x)=e^{-x^2+2x}$ and to take the FT of it, I complete the square:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=e^{-x^2+2x \pm1}=e^{-(x-1)^2}e
\end{equation}
Then, by knowing that the FT of $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$ is:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}[g(x)](k)=\hat{g}(k)=\frac{e^{-k^2/4}}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}
I make use of the property:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=g(x-a) \Rightarrow \mathcal{F}[f(x)](k)=e^{-iax}\hat{g}(k)
\end{equation}
I can see that for a=1:

\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(k)=ee^{-ik}\hat{g}(k)=\frac{e^{-(k+2i)^2/4}}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}
But I see on the book that the correct answer is:

\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(k)=\frac{e^{-(k-2i)^2/4}}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}
Why is that minus over there? I cannot see my mistake :/

Thank you!

Comment: What is your definition for the Fourier transform? The answer hinges on that. Most commonly the Fourier kernel has a negative sign in the exponent which changes the translation property.

Comment: I use the definition that Leucippus uses below, but still I get the "+" sign instead of "-".. :/

Comment: You made a typo in your post then. The RHS of the translation property should be $e^{-iak}\hat{g}(k)$. In which case, I think this is a typo in the text. I've worked it out myself and double checked with Mathematica.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Oh, yes you are right, it is a "-" there, I am so sorry! But even if it has a minus, I still get "+" sign in the final result since I did the method including the minus sign, while I made a typo over here

Comment: Yes I know. That's why I said I am pretty sure it's a typo in the book. It should have a negative sign, not a positive sign. Typos like this are common in papers which are much shorter than books. Books are *rife* with minor typos like this.

Comment: @CameronWilliams But did you find the result to be with a minus or a plus? Cause I checked with Mathematica too and it does have a minus, but while using $e^{-iak}\hat{g}(k)$ I still get the plus in the end :/

Comment: Mathematica *does not* use the same definition of the Fourier transform as the one you are using as default. It uses the opposite convention where there the sign is positive in the Fourier kernel. You have to use FourierParameters->{0,-1} to get the convention you are using.

Comment: @CameronWilliams So I am getting the correct result, by using the definition with the minus sign for the kernel right?

Comment: Yes you most definitely are.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you so much I lost a lot of time, just to make sure that I am doing it the right way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the Fourier transform be defined as
\begin{align}
f(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, e^{-i \omega x} \, dx
\end{align}
Now, for $f(x) = e^{- x^{2} + 2x}$ the following is developed.
\begin{align}
2 \pi \, f(\omega) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- (x^2 - (2 - i\omega) x)} \, dx \\
&= e^{-\left(1 - \frac{i \omega}{2}\right)^{2}} \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- \left(x - 1 + \frac{i \omega}{2}\right)^{2}} \, dx \\
&= e^{-\left(1 - \frac{i \omega}{2}\right)^{2}} \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- u^{2}} \, du \hspace{10mm} u=x-1+\frac{i\omega}{2} \\
&= 2 \, e^{-\left(1 - \frac{i \omega}{2}\right)^{2}} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- u^{2}} \, du \\
&= e^{-\left(1 - \frac{i \omega}{2}\right)^{2}} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- t} \, t^{-1/2} \, dt \hspace{10mm} t = u^{2} \\
&= \sqrt{\pi} \, e^{-\left(1 - \frac{i \omega}{2}\right)^{2}}.
\end{align}
This leads to
\begin{align}
f(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \, e^{-\left(1 - \frac{i \omega}{2}\right)^{2}}.
\end{align}

---

Method 2:

Using the properties
\begin{align}
f(t-t_{0}) &= f(\omega) \, e^{- i \omega t_{0}} \\
f(e^{- t^{2}}) &= \sqrt{\pi} \, e^{- \frac{\omega^{2}}{4}}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
F\{ e^{-x^{2}+ 2x}; \omega\} &= e \, F\{ e^{-(x-1)^{2}}; \omega\} = e^{1 - i \omega} \, F\{e^{-x^{2}}; \omega\} = \sqrt{\pi} \, e^{1 - i \omega - \frac{\omega^{2}}{4}} = \sqrt{\pi} \, e^{\left(1 - \frac{i \omega}{2}\right)^{2}}
\end{align}
- as it appears the definitions of the properties used here remove the general minus sign of the exponential.

Comment: That is correct, but the problem is that I am asked to not use any integral in order to compute the FT, but just the properties that arise from the Fourier transformation. The definition is the one you use here too, and while I use the translation property I cannot end up with the "-" sign. Is there any mistake at the method I used during my question?

Comment: @Mitscaype A few lines have been added. The minus signs are tricky as can be seen.

Answer (score 3):

I propose another method that does not use integration. Problem is in the change of variable when completing the square : because of the imaginary unit $i$, the new variable is complex and thus the integral must be done carefully in $\mathbb{C}$.

As $f$ is smooth (i.e. $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty\left(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R}\right)$), $\hat{f}$ is also smooth. Since we have
$$f'=-2(x-1)f$$
we obtain thanks to the properties of the Fourier transformation
$$ik\hat{f}=-2i\hat{f}'+2\hat{f}$$
i.e.
$$\hat{f}'=-\frac{(ik+2)}{2i}\hat{f}.$$
Then, on can easily check that a solution of this EDO is given by
$$\hat{f}(k)=C\mathrm{e}^{-k^2/4+ik}\quad\quad C\in\mathbb{R}.$$
You can seek the constant C by letting $k\to0$ (use the continuity under integral criterion to link $\hat{f}(0)$ to $f$).

Comment: I find it interesting that you used the acronym EDO instead of ODE. Are you from a romantic language speaking country?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Really smart! Indeed, I am French!